# Shell Script to capture file name and file size in CSV format

Tags: shell, csv

I have number of zip files in a certain folder.
I want to capture file name and the size of the file in a csv format containing file names and sizes, one file per day. The file names do contain the date.

Files are in `/somedirectory/archive/test`

```
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  30 17:09 XXXXX_20140530_0401_28.txt.gz
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  30 17:09 XXXXX_20140530_0401_29.txt.gz
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 AAAA AAAA 9.3M May  31 17:09 XXXXX_20140531_0401_01.txt.gz
```

Now I want to crate a cronjob to run everyday and capture the same csvs.

test30052014.csv

```
"XXXXX_20140530_0401_28.txt.gz","9.3","May 30"
"XXXXX_20140530_0401_29.txt.gz","9.3","May 30"
```

test31052014.csv

```
"XXXXX_20140531_0401_01.txt.gz","9.3","May 31"
```

Comment: If you ask such a question then always provide example input **and** the desired output.

Comment: i think i have already provided the input which should be consider like file name date wise and size. And output as well i have given need csv format file name and size of the file

Comment: ... and "everyday wise" means what? and do you want the file names only, or the path relative to the current directory, or the full path?

Comment: I am sorry if there is any gap in understanding. i never said that "everyday wise". I just mentioned what i mention.and it is clearly mentioned that i want csv file where the listed 2 files i mentioned should be there (obviously only name) and size (9.3 M) and every day i am getting the same file (20140530 this the date which change every day) so i have to take the file name pattern as input and send the all file name and size as output in he csv file .

Comment: @test I've added example output to your question, based on your comment. Please fix it if its not correct. BTW: To format blocks of "code", put 4 spaces in front, or use the {} button.

Comment: @derobert thanks for the help. this is the thing i am looking.

Comment: I've cut the question drastically, hoping it will make a bit more sense. Two things: in the first half (that I've removed) you didn't have the day column ("May 30") - such column doesn't make much sense since 1) `ls` changes the output depending on how old the files are (the column may or may not contain year as well) and 2) the date is contained in a fixed format in the CSV file name and also in the names of the files listed therein. You should probably think a bit more about what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

If your system has GNU coreutils, then the easiest and most reliable way to get human-readable file sizes is probably via the `du` command. To print the output into the format you want, using bash you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -rd $'\0' size name
do 
  printf '"%s","%s"\n' "${name##*/}" "$size"
done < <(du -0h /somedirectory/archive/test/XXXXX_20140530_*.gz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a quick shell script (well call it size.sh for the sake of example):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
for LINE in $(ls -1s --block-size=k|tail -n +2); do 
  echo $LINE|awk '{ print "\""$2"\",\""$1"\"" }'
done
```

It outputs the sizes consistently in kilobytes, and you can just redirect the output of the script to your file..

```
size.sh > $(date +%Y-%m-%d).csv
```